# String retrieve Function in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I am having a database with 2 columns employee and job.Job column contains character in each record.In that,I have to list the employees whose job is having last 3 characters as 'man'.I have to use only functions in SQL Query.

Comment: Please Consider my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer For Question 4 is

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE SUBSTR(job,-3,3)='MAN';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIKE` with wildcard:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE job_column_name LIKE '%man'
```

or using `RIGHT`

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE RIGHT(job_column_name, 3) = 'man'
```